# How do I throw out (or pick off) base stealers in RBI Baseball 14?

Tags: android, rbi-baseball-14

I'm playing the Android version of [RBI Baseball 14](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mlb.RBIBaseball&hl=en).

The CPU players will often steal second base.  I can have my catcher throw to second, but although I tap the second base button as soon as the catcher gets the ball, and I think my reflexes are reasonably good, over dozens of games I have never managed to throw out the runner.

Is there a trick to this?  Are my reflexes just too slow?  Is there a bug in the game making it impossible?

Whenever I try to steal second against the CPU, they almost always throw me out.

On a related note, when there is a runner leading off first, I can tap the little inset box to have my pitcher try a pickoff throw to first.  Over dozens of games and hundreds of throws, I have never successfully picked off the runner - they always get back in time.  (I'm not sure it deters them from stealing second, either.)  Again, is there a trick to pickoffs, or is this impossible, or just very low probability?